# Facebook Paper-like Headline Drag Up then Down to Snap to bottom of Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xcode5

I have created a Facebook Paper-like app and I'm trying to figure out how the View can be dragged / snapped to the bottom, then dragged back up. I'm pretty sure I have it 75% completed but I can't for the life of me figure out how to have it snap to the bottom.
Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)onDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint center = self.headlinesView.center;

    // this is how high the tray should go
    int upperThreshold = self.view.frame.size.height - (self.headlinesView.frame.size.height / 2);
    // this is how low the tray should go
    int lowerThreshold = self.view.frame.size.height + (self.headlinesView.frame.size.height / 2);

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"start");
        // reset the tray location to where the tray currently is
        self.originalTrayLocation = self.headlinesView.center;
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"changed");

        if (center.y < upperThreshold) {
            // if the tray location is past the point where it should go,
            // add some resistance
            center.y = upperThreshold + (translation.y * 0.1);
        } else if (center.y > lowerThreshold) {
            // if the user drags down the tray a lot, don't make the tray
            // go that low
            center.y = lowerThreshold;
        } else {
            // drag as normal
            center.y = self.originalTrayLocation.y + translation.y;
        }
        self.headlinesView.center = center;
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"ended");
        // if the user dragged too far up or down, animate the tray
        // back to its desired location
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.headlinesView.center = CGPointMake(160, upperThreshold);
        }];
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi, I am going to do same thing. Do u have any idea....